# wait for a Task that calls an async method to complete without blocking thread

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, task

I am trying to execute 2 tasks in succession, but the second task is running before the first task has completely finished because it is awaitable

```
var task1 = new Task(async () =>
{
    Trace.WriteLine("before delay");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Trace.WriteLine("after delay");
});

task1.ContinueWith(task => Trace.WriteLine("continued"));

task1.Start();
task1.Wait();
```

I would like to elicit the output

```
before delay 
after delay 
continued
```

but I get

```
before delay
continued
```

Is there a way to block task1 without holding up the thread?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your async lambda returns early making `new Task` think the task is done. It returns at the first `await`. The task constructor is off limits! Don't use it (almost never).

It's existence is basically a design bug in the framework. Unstarted tasks should not even exist and the `Start` method should be deleted. We have `TaskCompletionSource` for that.

Use `Task.Run(async () => ...`. `Task.Run` has special support for `Task` returning functions.

Comment: He also needs to assign the result of `task1.ContinueWith(...)` to another task and wait on that task instead of `task1`.

Comment: Great! Where can I get more details of the inner working & best practices for this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any such place. There should be a site detailing the most common 10 issues with the TPL. Really, 95% of Stack Overflow questions stem from 10 issues.

Comment: @ArghyaC, check [TPL](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/task-parallel-library/info) and [async/await](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/async-await/info) tag wikis. They have a plethora of useful links. Besides, I wouldn't normally recommend a non-free resource, but do get a copy of [Stephen Cleary's book](http://stephencleary.com/book/).

Comment: @ArghyaC: I've been working on a [tour of Task](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/04/a-tour-of-task-part-0-overview.html) where I try to point out which APIs are for which purposes (and which should be avoided entirely).

Comment: @Noseratio thanks for the useful link! I'll go through them check the cookbook definitely.

Comment: @StephenCleary Ah! This is great! I'll read through this and get your book as well. Does the book cover Task in TPL or the async-await as well? BTW, I'm the user type 1.5 who used TPL Tasks incompletely and jumped into aa construct!

Comment: @ArghyaC: As far as tasks go, my book mainly covers using them for `async`. The parallel approaches in (most of) my book use higher-level constructs like `Parallel` and PLINQ.

Answer (score 2):

To complement @usr's answer, I think it's worth showing how to make your existing code work, with these minor changes:

```
Task<Task> task1 = new Task<Task>(new Func<Task>(async () =>
{
    Trace.WriteLine("before delay");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Trace.WriteLine("after delay");
}));

var task2 = task1.Unwrap();

var task3 = task2.ContinueWith(task => Trace.WriteLine("continued"));

task1.Start();
task3.Wait();
```

Hope this helps to understand the actual task workflow better. [`Task.Unwrap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee795275(v=vs.110).aspx) can be a power tool if used properly.

That said, you indeed should not need to create a `Task` object via its constructor. To learn more, check TPL's Stephen Toub blog posts:

- [Task.Factory.StartNew vs new Task(...).Start](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/06/13/10024153.aspx)
- [Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx).
- [Processing Sequences of Asynchronous Operations with Tasks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/11/21/10094564.aspx)